# Rshiny data classification and summary statistics errors

Tags: r, shiny, tree, classification, summary

I'm new to Rshiny. I have been tasked with the following:

Write a shiny app which uses a Navbar, with headings "Data Exploration" and
"Classification tools", so that, within the *Data Exploration tab*, the user can:

1. choose any variable and see summary statistics of it,
2. use a select input to see summary statistics of a variable by Rate category.
3. see a plot of the beertax variable by Rate group when the app is first opened.
4. Choose any variable and visualise its relationship with the Rate variable. Different
   plots should appear depending on whether the selected variable is continuous or categorical.

within the *Classification tools tab*, the user can:

1. use a slider input to select from (0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8), the proportion of data used
   for the training data set (we will not be using the test data here, so you should use the
   complement proportion for the validation data set.)
2. view a classification tree for the training data, and use the radio buttons to either
   "view pruned tree" or "view unpruned tree". Where, for the pruned tree, pruning should be
   done using the cp value that corresponds with the smallest xerror.
3. see both the correct- and miss- classification rates (using the validation data) for the
   pruned classification tree and one of LDA or QDA, these results should be presented in a
   table. The "best" classification method, i.e. that with the lowest missclassification rate,
   should be highlighted and there should be a note to inform the user of what the
   highlighting means.
4. make a prediction of the Rate status (i.e. above or below the US average) of an average
   unseen state, using the "best" classification method, with a user defined set of observed
   variable values (i.e. input options will be needed to allow the user to input their desired
   observed values). The default user defined values, that appear when the app is opened,
   should be the mean of the continuous variables and the mode of the categorical variables.
   There should also be a warning which alerts the user when they are extrapolating.

Currently, I've pretty much completed up to step 3 of the Classification tools tab. However, I'm experiencing various errors that I need help with. I'll talk about them in order:

1. When I run the app after opening Rstudio, my first tab 'Data Exploration' runs fine. However, whenever I reload the app, the summary table fails and I get the error '*unused argument (input$variable)*'. I'm not sure why this is happening.
2. When I run the app, there appears an error on the second tab 'Classification tools' which reads '*non-numeric argument to binary operator*'. I investigated what this meant and I think I understand it but i'm just not sure how this error applies to my code. Instead of this error, my aim is to generate a table which includes the classification rate and missclassification rate of the CART model and eventually the LDA model too (dependent on the training data proportion input).
3. Following from issue 2, I investigated my code and realised that I think the previous error occurs due to the line *lda.pred <- predict(lda.model, newdata = valid.data[,-6])* and so I removed the code to see what would happen and then I end up with a new error '*unused argument (pred == valid.label)*'. Again, I don't understand why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
data <- read.csv("Fatality-task2.csv")

data$Rate <- as.factor(data$Rate)

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(markdown)
library(gtsummary)
library(ggdendro)
library(factoextra)
library(mclust)
library(cluster)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
#library(MASS)

#################################################################


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("Data Exploration",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput("variable",
                                      "Variable",
                                      colnames(data)),
                          selectInput("rate",
                                      "Rate",
                                      levels(data$Rate))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tableOutput("table"),
                          plotOutput("plot")
                        )
                      )    
             ),
             tabPanel("Classification tools",
                      sidebarLayout( 
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput("train.prop",
                                      "Training data proportion",
                                      min = 0.4,
                                      max = 0.8,
                                      step = 0.1,
                                      value = 0.6),
                          radioButtons("prune",
                                       "Pruning option",
                                       choices = c("view pruned tree",
                                                   "view unpruned tree"))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tableOutput("table2"),
                          plotOutput("plot2")
                          
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)




#################################################################

server <- function(input, output) {
  sum <- reactive({
    data <- data %>%
      filter(Rate == input$rate) %>%
      select(input$variable) %>%
      summary() %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      tidyr::separate(Freq, c("Stat", "Value"), sep=":") %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from =Stat, values_from = Value)
    data <- data[, -c(1,2)]
    
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    sum()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$variable == "jaild" | input$variable == "Rate"){
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, fill = data[[input$variable]])) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
        if (input$variable == "Rate"){
          theme(legend.position = "none")
        }
    } else {
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, y = data[[input$variable]], fill = Rate)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    }
    
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    
    set.seed(1234)
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*input$train.prop))
    ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], length(c(1:n)[-ind1]))
    
    
    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]
    
    
    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")
    
    ptree <- prune(fit.tree, cp = fit.tree$cptable[which.min(fit.tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])
    
    if (input$prune == "view pruned tree"){
      rpart.plot(ptree, uniform =TRUE)
    } else {
      rpart.plot(fit.tree)
    }
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  #######################
  table <- reactive({
    #################################
    library(MASS)
    set.seed(1234)
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*input$train.prop))
    #ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], length(c(1:n)[-ind1]))
    ind2 <- setdiff(c(1:n), ind1)
    
    
    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]
    
    train.label <- data[ind1, 6]
    valid.label <- data[ind2, 6]
    
    #################################
    
    ### fit cart model
    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")
    
    ### prune the tree
    ptree <- prune(fit.tree, cp = fit.tree$cptable[which.min(fit.tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])
    
    ### predict using the validation data on the pruned tree
    pred <- predict(ptree, newdata = valid.data, type = "class")
    
    ### lda
    
    lda.model <- lda(train.data[,-6], train.label)
    
    #lda.pred <- predict(lda.model, newdata = valid.data[,-6])
    
    
    ### create a classification table
    
    
    
    CCR <- sum(pred == valid.label)/nrow(valid.data)
    MCR <- 1 - CCR
    
    CR <- c(CCR, MCR)
    
    CR <- as.data.frame(CR)
    colnames(CR) <- "CART"
    rownames(CR) <- c("CCR", "MCR")
    
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  #############################
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    table()
    
  }) 
  
}




#################################################################
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And my app output looks like this in the above 3 cases (in order)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm desperate for help so any help is appreciated. If you need any clarification on the code, then let me know please.

~edit~

here is my updated code after solving my second and third errors (i think?):

```
data <- read.csv("Fatality-task2.csv")

data$Rate <- as.factor(data$Rate)

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(markdown)
library(gtsummary)
library(ggdendro)
library(factoextra)
library(mclust)
library(cluster)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
#library(MASS)

dput(head(data))

#################################################################


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("Data Exploration",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput("variable",
                                      "Variable",
                                      colnames(data)),
                          selectInput("rate",
                                      "Rate",
                                      levels(data$Rate))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tableOutput("table"),
                          plotOutput("plot")
                        )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Classification tools",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput("train.prop",
                                      "Training data proportion",
                                      min = 0.4,
                                      max = 0.8,
                                      step = 0.1,
                                      value = 0.6),
                          radioButtons("prune",
                                       "Pruning option",
                                       choices = c("view pruned tree",
                                                   "view unpruned tree"))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tableOutput("table2"),
                          plotOutput("plot2")
                          
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)




#################################################################

server <- function(input, output) {
  sum <- reactive({
    req(input$variable,input$rate)
    data <- data %>%
      filter(Rate == input$rate) %>%
      select(input$variable) %>%
      summary() %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      tidyr::separate(Freq, c("Stat", "Value"), sep=":") %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from =Stat, values_from = Value)
    data <- data[, -c(1,2)]
    
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    sum()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$variable)
    if (input$variable == "jaild" | input$variable == "Rate"){
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, fill = .data[[as.name(input$variable)]])) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
        if (input$variable == "Rate"){
          theme(legend.position = "none")
        }
    } else {
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, y = .data[[as.name(input$variable)]], fill = Rate)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    }
    
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$train.prop,input$prune)
    set.seed(1234)
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*as.numeric(input$train.prop)))
    ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], length(c(1:n)[-ind1]))
    
    
    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]
    
    
    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")
    
    ptree <- prune(fit.tree, cp = fit.tree$cptable[which.min(fit.tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])
    
    if (input$prune == "view pruned tree"){
      rpart.plot(ptree, uniform =TRUE)
    } else {
      rpart.plot(fit.tree)
    }
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  #######################
  table <- reactive({
    #################################
    library(MASS)
    set.seed(1234)
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*input$train.prop))
    #ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], length(c(1:n)[-ind1]))
    ind2 <- setdiff(c(1:n), ind1)
    
    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]
    
    #################################
    
    ### fit cart model
    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")
    
    ### prune the tree
    ptree <- prune(fit.tree, cp = fit.tree$cptable[which.min(fit.tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])
    
    ### predict using the validation data on the pruned tree
    pred <- predict(ptree, newdata = valid.data[,-6], type = "class")
    
    ### lda
    
     #lda.model <- lda(train.data[,-6], train.data[,6])
     
     lda.model <- lda(Rate~., data = train.data)
     
    
     lda.pred <- predict(lda.model, newdata = valid.data)
    
    
    ### create a classification table
    
    length(lda.model)
    
    
    x <- pred == valid.data[,6]
    
    CCR <- length(x[x == TRUE])/nrow(valid.data)
    MCR <- 1 - CCR
    
    CR <- c(CCR, MCR)
    
    z <- lda.pred$class == valid.data[,6]
    
    lda.CCR <- length(z[z == TRUE])/nrow(valid.data)
    lda.MCR <- 1 - CCR
    
    lda.CR <- c(lda.CCR, lda.MCR)
    
    y <- cbind(CR, lda.CR)
    
    y <- as.data.frame(y)
    colnames(y) <- c("CART", "LDA")
    rownames(y) <- c("CCR", "MCR")
    y
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  #############################
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    table()
    
  },
  rownames = TRUE) 
  
}




#################################################################
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

however my app didn't save last time when I solved the issues so I had to try and solve the errors again from memory. I think I did it correctly.

here is a snippet of my data too,

[image]

"beertax","jaild","vmiles","unrate","perinc","Rate"
1.53937947750092,"no",7.23388720703125,14.3999996185303,10544.15234375,1
1.78899073600769,"no",7.83634765625,13.6999998092651,10732.7978515625,1
1.71428561210632,"no",8.262990234375,11.1000003814697,11108.791015625,1
1.65254235267639,"no",8.7269169921875,8.89999961853027,11332.626953125,1
1.60990703105927,"no",8.952853515625,9.80000019073486,11661.5068359375,1
1.55999994277954,"no",9.1663017578125,7.80000019073486,11944,1
1.50144362449646,"no",9.6743232421875,7.19999980926514,12368.6240234375,1
0.214797139167786,"yes",6.81015673828125,9.89999961853027,12309.0693359375,1
0.206422030925751,"yes",6.58749462890625,9.10000038146973,12693.8076171875,1
0.296703308820724,"yes",6.70997021484375,5,13265.93359375,1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `req()` and `as.numeric()` should fix the first two issues.  You should be able to fix the last one after this.

**EDIT**

Changing `select(input$variable)` to `dplyr::select(input$variable)` should eliminate your first error. There are 4 other packages with the same function `select()`, in your list of packages; hence you need to specify which package you intend to use it from or load `dplyr` last.

```
df1 <- read.table(text='"beertax","jaild","vmiles","unrate","perinc","Rate"
1.53937947750092,"no",7.23388720703125,14.3999996185303,10544.15234375,1
1.78899073600769,"no",7.83634765625,13.6999998092651,10732.7978515625,1
1.71428561210632,"no",8.262990234375,11.1000003814697,11108.791015625,1
1.65254235267639,"no",8.7269169921875,8.89999961853027,11332.626953125,1
1.60990703105927,"no",8.952853515625,9.80000019073486,11661.5068359375,1
1.55999994277954,"no",9.1663017578125,7.80000019073486,11944,1
1.50144362449646,"no",9.6743232421875,7.19999980926514,12368.6240234375,1
0.214797139167786,"yes",6.81015673828125,9.89999961853027,12309.0693359375,1
0.206422030925751,"yes",6.58749462890625,9.10000038146973,12693.8076171875,1
0.296703308820724,"yes",6.70997021484375,5,13265.93359375,1', header=TRUE, sep=",")

df2 <- df1 %>% transform(Rate=2)
data<- rbind(df1,df2)
data$Rate <- as.factor(data$Rate)

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(markdown)
library(gtsummary)
library(ggdendro)
library(factoextra)
library(mclust)
library(cluster)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(MASS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Testing Data Exploration",
             tabPanel("Data Exploration",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput("variable",
                                      "Variable",
                                      colnames(data)),
                          selectInput("rate",
                                      "Rate",
                                      levels(data$Rate))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          DTOutput("table1"),
                          plotOutput("plot")
                        )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Classification tools",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput("train.prop",
                                      "Training data proportion",
                                      min = 0.4,
                                      max = 0.8,
                                      step = 0.1,
                                      value = 0.6),
                          radioButtons("prune",
                                       "Pruning option",
                                       choices = c("view pruned tree",
                                                   "view unpruned tree"))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          DTOutput("table2"),
                          plotOutput("plot2")

                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  summ <- reactive({
    req(input$variable,input$rate)

    data1 <- data %>%
      filter(Rate == input$rate) %>%
      dplyr::select(input$variable) %>%
      summary() %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      tidyr::separate(Freq, c("Stat", "Value"), sep=":") %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Stat, values_from = Value)
    data2 <- data1[, -c(1,2)]
    data2
  })

  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    summ()
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$variable)
    if (input$variable == "jaild" | input$variable == "Rate"){
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, fill = .data[[as.name(input$variable)]])) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
        if (input$variable == "Rate"){
          theme(legend.position = "none")
        }
    } else {
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, y = .data[[as.name(input$variable)]], fill = Rate)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    }
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$train.prop,input$prune)
    set.seed(1234)
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*as.numeric(input$train.prop)))
    ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], length(c(1:n)[-ind1]))


    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]


    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")

    ptree <- prune(fit.tree, cp = fit.tree$cptable[which.min(fit.tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])

    if (input$prune == "view pruned tree"){
      rpart.plot(ptree, uniform =TRUE)
    } else {
      rpart.plot(fit.tree)
    }
  })
  #######################
  table <- reactive({

    set.seed(1234)
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*input$train.prop))
    #ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], length(c(1:n)[-ind1]))
    ind2 <- setdiff(c(1:n), ind1)

    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]

    #################################

    ### fit cart model
    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")

    ### prune the tree
    ptree <- prune(fit.tree, cp = fit.tree$cptable[which.min(fit.tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])

    ### predict using the validation data on the pruned tree
    pred <- predict(ptree, newdata = valid.data[,-6], type = "class")

    ### lda

    #lda.model <- lda(train.data[,-6], train.data[,6])

    lda.model <- lda(Rate~., data = train.data)


    lda.pred <- predict(lda.model, newdata = valid.data)

    ### create a classification table

    length(lda.model)


    x <- pred == valid.data[,6]

    CCR <- length(x[x == TRUE])/nrow(valid.data)
    MCR <- 1 - CCR

    CR <- c(CCR, MCR)

    z <- lda.pred$class == valid.data[,6]

    lda.CCR <- length(z[z == TRUE])/nrow(valid.data)
    lda.MCR <- 1 - CCR

    lda.CR <- c(lda.CCR, lda.MCR)

    y <- cbind(CR, lda.CR)

    y <- as.data.frame(y)
    colnames(y) <- c("CART", "LDA")
    rownames(y) <- c("CCR", "MCR")
    y
  })

  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    table()
  }, rownames = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I've been able to figure out my 2 last errors since I posted this question, however I wasn't able to use your code to sort out my first error. Any other ideas? It still comes up with the same error.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `data[[as.name(input$variable)]]` instead of `data[[input$variable]]`.  Please post some sample data - use `dput(head(data))` and post it back in your question, so that we can verify your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to use the command dput(head(data)) so I just took a screenshot of some of my data. I've updated my question with my updated code and my screenshot if that helps? Let me know if you need more from me please

Comment: Oh and I tried the code **data[[as.name(input$variable)]]** but I still got the first error.

Comment: perhaps you can paste 10 records from the .csv file.  Screen shot does not help.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my question again - is that what you meant for me to do or what?

Comment: Yes, let me try with your data.

Comment: Okay. Any luck?

Comment: No worries, thanks a lot for trying - there's absolutely no rush. Enjoy dinner.

Comment: Please change `select(input$variable)` to `dplyr::select(input$variable)`.  That should eliminate your first error.  There are 4 other packages with the same function `select()`, in your list of packages; hence you need to specify which package you intend to use it from or load `dplyr` last.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I did what you said and it worked. Thanks so much, I appreciate the help!